# took John to the hospital

Tags: adjectives, commas, placement

a. I took John to the hospital unconscious.

b. I took John unconscious to the hospital.

c. I took John, unconscious, to the hospital.

Which of the above are grammatical and meaningful?

Obviously I couldn't have been unconscious when I took John to the hospital, so John
has to be the one who is unconscious.

I think (a) is the only one that works. I think (c) might work in speech but isn't really grammatical.

Answer (score 1):

Form ***a*** is often used, but it is ambigous.

> a. I took John to the hospital unconscious.

You could write, "I took John to the hospital ***while John was*** unconscious.

**b** is missing commas around the word, "unconscious".

**c** is fine

> I took John, unconscious, to the hospital.

Comment: No, we would say _I took John to the hospital while **he** was unconscious._

Answer (score 0):

To remove any ambiguity you could say

> John was unconscious so I took him to the hospital.